# How to create a custom listing page in Magento

Tags: magento, catalog

I want to create custom product listing page, that list page does not related to any category.  It should list all the products which created in last 30 days.

Can any one help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just check the browser url in List.php block file and change the query as per our need.

Answer (score 0):

If I was posed with a similar task what I would do is simply create a category under the root category, doing so gives me capability of using all the features that magento supports for categories like URL path, making it visible in navigation, ability to define metas and title etc.

Now I would make use of Magento API (category and product list) and write
a script that marks all products which were created less than 30 days ago and remove product which were created more than 30 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Create a CMS page.

Add a block to this CMS e.g Class NameSpace_Catalog_Block_Product_CustomListing

Refering to function protected function _getProductCollection() you create a function that will collect collection and
a public function getLoadedProductCollection() that can be called from your CMS page.

Also make sure to register your module.